# project.assets.json doesn't have a target for 'net472'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net472' VS2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, sdk, microsoft.build

I get this error when i try to build the app.
I think somehow i need to do a .net restore but i dont know if it will work.. And i want to make it via code.
The .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions" Version="2.0.36" />
  <Import Project="..\..\..\..\MSBuild\root_configuration.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputPath>$(NUnitTestBinDir)\NunitTSAdapter</OutputPath>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NUnitTestAdapter\NUnitTestAdapter.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NunitTSFeature\NunitTSFeature.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? and let us know any progress about this issue. And we are willing to help you further. Besides, if you already have a solution, please share it here.

Comment: no, i dont have any solution yet

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the `obj` folder from your project folder and then build again, you will not face the issue.

**Update 1**

Right-click on the Project on the **Solution Explorer**-->**Properties**-->**Build Event**

write these on the `pre-build event command line`:

```
del  obj\project.assets.json
dotnet restore
```

[image]

Comment: and without deleting that? is there any other way?

Comment: You have to delete that file and then re-generate a new one by `dotnet restore` command. The previous solution which is provide by me is not an automated way, which makes you dissatisfied with that. So, I have an automated msbuild script function for you and you did not have to delete the file every time manually.

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check it:-)

Comment: this way works, but i am still looking for a long time way to work, and for every one

Answer (score 1):

I deleted both bin and obj folder within src/common, src/domain, and src/ folders and then opened command prompt and changed to solution directory and run below command

```
dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 0):

i spent one day for this error. I tried a lot of ways but still not successfull, such as:

- reopen Visual studio
- delete /obj, /bin
- run dotnet clean/restore, reinstall workload...

Finally, i increased "Minimum Target Android Framework" in "Android targets" .csproj file, then it built OK. Maybe there is something wrong with .csproj file.